# Disable repeating posts when paginating random posts for a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

With the following code I can disable repeating all random posts when I do pagination, but I need to do it only for a specific category, I would appreciate your help please.

I am trying other options but I have no results.

```
    session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Comment: I think you might need to do a little more work on this function?  There is no attempt to find the category.   Also... I'm surprised that `session_start()` just works for you when it's in there like that, without causing other issues in WordPress.

Comment: @Howard E Could you help me with a correct code to achieve this please? my knowledge in programming is very basic.